# How to choose the JDK version for the SDK development？

Tags: sdk, java, java-6

I‘m working on a java project which will release the **SDK** to user.

I have no idea about choosing the right jdk version, **which version is best**?

As i know, the jdk1.6 and 1.7 have stopped to update, however, there still are many old systems and applications working on jdk 1.6. I worry about that if i choose the newest version(jdk 1.8), the user with old jre will face the challenge.

It's best if post the jdk version download link.

Thanks.

PS：I am working on Mac OS X 10.10.2

Comment: You mean you are creating an API? You can opt to compile it in all versions. But if you rely heavily on Java 8, then it's not worth the time you will spend. At this moment 1.6 is the absolute minimum. Skip 1.7 like so many APIs and get to 1.8 immediately. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Java has `backward compatibility`.

All programs which work with `1.5` will work with `1.8` as well.

***Download Links***:

- [JDK 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
- [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Comment: Maybe JDK 1.8 is good choice, but if the SDK developing on the jdk version, how to ensure the jre 1.6 work right?

Comment: @JerikcXIONG Which IDE are you using?

Comment: IDE is not the problem. Maybe eclipse.